# Android Studio Spotify API does not work when dowmloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, spotify

I've made an android app in Android Studio which uses the Spotify API but it can not connect to the Spotify Remote when the app is installed from Google Play but it does work properly when i install it from my computer in debug and release mode too and I also have the the quota extension for my API on my Spotify developer dashboard. When the app is installed from play store the app tries to connect to spotify remote as my phone indicates but it fails connecting as the OnFail interrupts is triggered in this case. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Upvoted question. Would you able to figure out a solution to this problem? I have the same thing